# Return the second most frequent text in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I return the **second** most frequent text in a column?

I know that I can find the most frequent text in A2:A60 by using =INDEX(A2:A60;MODE(MATCH(A2:A60;A2:A60;0)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a similar method, this should give you the text(s) whose frequency is immediately below the highest frequency regardless of ties:

```
=LET(range,A1:A9,
uniques,UNIQUE(range),
counts,COUNTIF(range,uniques),
sCounts,UNIQUE(SORT(counts,1,-1)),
FILTER(uniques,counts=INDEX(sCounts,2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(UNIQUE(A1:A9),COUNTIF(A1:A9,UNIQUE(A1:A9)),-1),2)
```

Note that this will currently return the 2nd row from the array even if there is a tie. In case you don't want to return ties at the top:

```
=LET(a,UNIQUE(A1:A9),b,COUNTIF(A1:A9,a),TAKE(SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(a,b),b<MAX(b)),2,-1),1,1))
```